# on click add class to aspx linkbutton with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, linkbutton

I have many link buttons with various contents like tabs, i need to apply a class to clicked link button with jquery, am using bellow function but its not working when post backing the page

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly you need to do? something like on first click add class and second click remove class or .... ???

Comment: apply css class to tabs on click in asp linkbutton

Answer (score 1):

This won't work they way you're expecting it to becuase the class is added and then the page is refreshed.

You don't really need any Javascript for this, here's how I do it.

Each page has it's own ID

```
<body id="aboutPage">
```

and each menu item has its own ID too:

```
<li id="aboutMenuItem">About</li>
```

Then in your CSS you can specifically hit the li for the page you're on:

```
#home #homeMenuItem,
#about #aboutMenuItem,
[...]
{
 /* Style for the selected menu item here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the click event or do something like this...

```
$(function() {
    $('a').live('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't work either. The live binding will simply perform the same as the click in this case and once the link is clicked, the class will be toggled and then the page refreshed - resetting everything back to its default.